# Is the leak instrument in Xcode instruments accurate?

Tags: swift, instruments, combine

I have the following code which should indicate a memory leak. but it actually doesn't when I test it with Xcode leak instrument.
Does this mean that there's actually no memory leak, or the instrument may be wrong?

```
private func initTimePublisher() {
        timer.publish(every: tickInterval, on: runloop, in: runloopMode)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { self.durationCalculator.activeDuration(between: self.startDate!, and: $0) }
            .assign(to: \.activeDuration, on: self) // This should be a retain cycle which causes a memory like right?
            .store(in: &subs)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program can have a retain cycle without having a memory leak.

Your program has some “root” values: global variables, variables on the stack, and thread-local variables. Your program can access these any of these values “from scratch”, without needing a reference to it from some other object.

Then your program has other objects reachable as properties of the root objects: the “children” of the roots. And it has objects reachable from properties of the children: the “grandchildren” of the roots. And so on. Some objects are reachable by multiple paths from roots.

So your program has a set of reachable objects: the roots and all of their descendants.

Any object which your program allocated and did not deallocate, and which is no longer in the reachable set, is leaked.

Now let's look at the code in your question.

- Is `self` leaked? You didn't say what `self` is. If it's referenced from a global variable, or it's in the view (or view controller) hierarchy, or otherwise reachable, it's not leaked.
- Is the publisher leaked? The publisher you built up with `Timer.publish(...).autoconnect().map{...}.assign(...)` is not leaked. It contains references to `self`, but it is destroyed when `initTimePublisher` returns.
- Is the `AnyCancellable` you store in `subs` leaked? If `self` is not leaked, then the `AnyCancellable` is reachable and so it is not leaked either.

Now, you may be confused because I said the publisher is destroyed when `initTimePublisher` returns. But you're still getting signals from the timer, right?

When you call `.assign(to:on:)` (or `.sink`), you create a `Subscription`. In fact, you create a graph of `Subscription` objects that generally mirrors the graph of `Publisher` objects you're subscribing to. Here's your `Publisher` graph:

```
Timer.Publisher <- Autoconnect <- Map
```

And so when you subscribe using the `.assign` operator, you get a `Subscription` graph that looks like this:

```
Timer.Publisher.Subscription <- Autoconnect.Subscription <- Map.Subscription
    <- Assign.Subscription
```

(Under the hood, Combine usually uses a name like `Conduit` or `Inner` for the `Subscription` type, so that's what you'll see in the memory inspector or in debug prints.)

The `AnyCancellable` you get back from `.assign`, which you store in `subs`, is a wrapper around the `Assign.Subscription`.

So, there are retain cycles in the subscription graph. The `Map.Subscription` object contains the closure you passed to `.map`, which contains a reference to `self`. And the `Assign.Subscription` contains a reference to `self` and a reference to the `Map.Subscription`. And `self` contains `subs`, which contains the `AnyCancellable` that wraps the `Assign.Subscription`.

But all of these objects are still reachable, not leaked, as long as `self` is reachable.

If you remove the `AnyCancellable` from `subs` and let it be destroyed, then it calls `cancel` on the `Assign.Subscription`. That tells the `Assign.Subscription` to discard its reference to `self` and to cancel its upstream subscription, the `Map.Subscription`. Then the `Map.Subscription` discards its reference to the closure and cancels its upstream subscription. And so on. Once the cancellation has propagated all the way up to the `Timer.Publisher.Subscription`, all of the retain cycles have been broken and all of the `Subscription` objects have been cleaned up. No leaks.

Comment: One more thing though..does this mean that the code above is generally acceptable and I don't have to use weak self every where with Combine? "Self" is a class used by a view model, which is used by a view of course.

Comment: It depends. Do you want these retain cycles to keep your `self` object (whatever it is) alive? If so, then the retain cycles are fine. But let's say your `self` is a `UIViewController` in a navigation stack, and you want it to be destroyed when it's popped from the stack. Then it would be appropriate to use `weak` to ensure that only the reference from the navigation stack is keeping `self` alive.